# how to activate two php scripts in html action tag at the same time?

Tags: php, html

I have two problems.

1. I want that when a user clicks on `Vlado` that the action will activate `PamtiOdabranogZastupnika.php` script in back-end and finally redirect the user to another web page.
2. I want that when you click on `Pošalji` that the action will activate **two** scripts, `upis_podataka.php` and `e_mail.php`.

Code:

```
<div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a data-toggle="pill" href="#forma_id" href="PamtiOdabranogZastupnika.php?vlado=true" ><img src="Vlado.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" name="vlado"></a> 
</div>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="upis_podataka.php" action="e_mail.php" method="POST">  
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji"/>
    </div>    
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to active a second PHP script using the first script.

Comment: Just create a new script which includes both? Note that you may have issues with globals and the like if the scripts are not properly written.

Comment: Okey, that can be good for my second problem. Thank you.
But bigger problem is how to activate PamtiOdabranogZastupnika.php and go to web form.
Its one page web design.
Script PamtiOdabranogZastupnika.php have few lines of code. It will write string in variable that is clicked.
For example if user click on Vlado picture, script will write "vlado" in variable.